# Adobe AIR dynamic sound and recording delay issue

Tags: ios, audio, air

I'm writing mobile application with Adobe AIR. The application use AIR Microphone API to record sound to file and later replay it.

The problem manifest only on mobile devices, not simulator. Specifically only on iOS devices, android devices seem to work OK.

1. Sometimes the recorded sound is missing samples. I know this because I use iFunBox to copy the recorded file to another application that replay it. The dropped frame manifest during playback as very fast audio because only part of the samples were recorded.
2. Sometime the playback is to slow which manifest as very slow audio. I know this because when the recording is fine and the other application play the sound right or when I take a file I recorded in the simulator (which run on my MacBook) and it only play slow on the mobile device.

How can I make sure the sound is good even when the application is a bit busy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built the application as ad-hoc package and install it on iPad using TestFlight and now everything seem to work just fine.

I guess during debug Adobe AIR did not manage to fill the sound buffer fast enough and cause the distortion.

Comment: I had similar results: turn traces off, don't use debug, and don't use interpreter packaging mode and the performance goes up dramatically. Kind of sucks for testing purposes, but what are you going to do, eh?